# how to access to dynamic path

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, readfile

i've node js application and I need to access to some path,the issue is that the path is having some dynamic property inside,how should I do that

```
app/appC.1222/Release.txt


app/appC.5555/Release.txt


app/appC.test/Release.txt
```

- the first app is constant
- the appC is constant
- and after the **.**it can be any alpha numeric
- the Relese.txt is also constant

I need to call it like

```
fs.readFileAsync('The dynamic path', 'utf8')
```

,any idea how to access to this path ?

The path **is not** in my app folders...
it can be like C://app/appC.test/Release.txt etc...

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

Comment: @Paulpro- thanks but how should I use it for create file that are not in my app folder ...

Comment: I do not think it is possible, see [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback). The value for *filename* is of String type, not a regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
^app\/appC\.[a-zA-Z\d]+\/Release\.txt$
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to do it with " "  at the begining or in the end ? and can I test it somethow ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.get('/app/appC.:param/Release.txt', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params.param);
    res.send("Everything looks normal here");
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I mean, I Need to provide path to the read file ....how express is helping here ?

Comment: Assume that the file in C, how should U put the path ?